# How to query mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got this code that I want to return all the products from a model and sort them by a query; the query behind the route `// ?sortBy=sold&order=desc&limit=100&skip=5`

And the controller I use for the route, I know I must be doing something incorrectly:

```
exports.menBySell = async (req, res, next) => {
  let order = req.query.order ? req.query.order : "asc";
  let sortBy = req.query.sortBy ? req.query.sortBy : "_id";
  let limit = req.query.limit ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : 100;

  try {
    const menBySell = await Men.find()
      .populate("color")
      .populate("brand")
      .sort([[sortBy, order]])
      .limit(limit)
      .exec(articles);
    return res.json(articles);
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: This post doesn't ask a clear question.  Try rephrasing it in a way that describes your intended result, as well as the error or unintended result you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function as below, that receives the filter object from your query string:

```
  const parseQueryFilter = (filter) => {
    if (!filter) {
        return {options: null, newFilter: {}};
    }
    let options = null, newFilter = Object.assign({}, filter);
    Object.keys(newFilter).forEach((k) => {
        try {
            if (k === 'sortBy') {
                console.log(filter[k]);
                options = {sort: JSON.parse(filter[k])};
                delete newFilter[k];
            } else {
                console.log(filter[k]);
                newFilter[k] = JSON.parse(filter[k]);
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
    });
    return {options, newFilter};
};
```

Then, you use this function passing the filter as parameter, and it will retrieve the options object (which will contain the options from your "sortBy" query string and the newFilter object containing the other parameters from query string.

```
let {options, newFilter} = parseQueryFilter(filter);
return Men.find(newFilter, null, options);
```